# If value matches vector in data.frame, return the value in adjacent column

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I define the following data.frame:

```
bolts <- data.frame(bolt = c("1/2","5/8","3/4","7/8","1"),
                hole = c(9/16,11/16,13/16,15/16,17/16))
```

Then I choose a value from `bolts$bolt` at random:

```
bolt <- sample(c("1/2","5/8","3/4","7/8","1"),1)
```

I want to write a code to return the corresponding `bolts$hole` to the selected bolt value. I tried the below but I got NULL:

```
hole <- for (bolt in bolts$bolt) {return(bolts$hole)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match`

```
bolts$hole[match(bolt, bolts$bolt)]
```

Or `==`

```
bolts$hole[bolts$bolt == bolt]
```